# How does Action Script 3 handle Asynchronous callbacks?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, asynchronous, garbage-collection

I have a piece of code in my game which looks a lot like this:

```
MultiplayerAPI.createGameRoom(function(){ successFunction(new Object()); });
```

Basically, the createGameRoom is performed and, upon success, the function I passed is run.

However I've been running into some strange bugs recently and I'm wondering, is the instance of "new Object();" the same each time the callback function is run?

It needs to be a different, fresh instance of Object each time, but I'm having some garbage collection issues which make me think it's passing the same object each time that event callback is fired,

Anyone have any idea how Flash handles this?

Comment: Please give us more code and information about object, which is being passed to your successFunction.

Comment: I imagine it's largely irrelevant as flash will either instantiate a new one or it won't, surely? The object is just a display object, the success function swaps the old object which was being displayed with the new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your example you call the method successFunction within the definition and not when the code should be executed. You have to pass a reference to the method instead of invoking it. Take a look at the following examples. If you use the apply method you can pass the arguments as Array.
*Nicholas

Function Reference & Function Call

```
function myFunction(parameter:String):String
{
    return 'hello '+parameter;
}

var myFunctionReference:Function = myFunction;
trace(myFunctionReference); // function Function() {}

trace(myFunctionReference('world')); // 'hello world'

var myFunctionReturnValue:String = myFunction('moon');
trace(myFunctionReturnValue); // 'hello moon'
```

Working Example

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class MethodTest extends Sprite
    {   
        public function MethodTest()
        {
            trace('MethodTest Constructor');
            trace('---');
            invoke(successFunction,'first',{id:123,type:'foo'}); 
            trace('---');
            invokeByApply(successFunction,'second',{id:456,type:'bar'});   
        }

        public function invoke(method:Function,someName:String, someObject:Object):void{
            trace('MethodTest invoke');
            method(someName,someObject);
        }

        public function invokeByApply(method:Function,...arguments):void{
            trace('MethodTest invokeByApply');
            method.apply(null,arguments);
        }

        public function successFunction(someName:String, someObject:Object):void{           
            trace('MethodTest successFunction');
            trace('someName: '+someName);
            for(var key:String in someObject)trace(key+': '+someObject[key]);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Writing AS3 code as in the example you gave (defining new functions from within the calls to other methods), as is done in JavaScript, you will find it very difficult to debug.

I suggest checking out "OOP with ActionScript" by Hall/Wan and taking advantage of object orientated programming design principles, as it may make your life easier in the long term:

[http://www.amazon.com/Object-Oriented-Programming-ActionScript-Branden-Hall/dp/0735711836](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735711836)